# multithreading not running task

Tags: python, python-multithreading

So I have been messing around with this multithreading all day long but can seem to get it to work. It's in Python 3 also.

The program is trying to generate a list of 5 words 1000 times and using multithreading to increase the speed.

I've changed the code to lots off different methods im been searching online but with no outcome.

With what I have at the moment it will run without any issue but not print any of the words.

Any chance someone could have a look over it.

```
import random
from threading import Thread

word_file = "words.txt"


def gen():
    Words = open(word_file).read().splitlines() #retreiving and sorting word file
    seed = random.randrange(0,2048) #amount of words to choose from in list

    for x in range(0, 1000):
        print(random.choices(Words, k=5)) #print the words

def main():
    t1 = Thread(target=gen)
    t2 = Thread(target=gen)
    t3 = Thread(target=gen)
    t4 = Thread(target=gen)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    t4.start()

print("completed")
```

Comment: Please correct the indentation in `gen` and `main`. Your code is incorrect in its current format.

Comment: @FatihAkici `gen` is reading the file and printing in the same function. And OP just so you know, multi threading doesn't automatically make something faster. Threading is good when your program is blocked by something, say an HTTP call or I/O. If you have a lot of work that you want to distribute what you want is multi processing, not multi threading.

Comment: Each spawned thread is performing File I/O; that disk can only be read so fast!

Comment: @user2896976 To clarify, Network I/O (server calls and such) is fine for threading, but File I/O (to disk, or even a network drive [fast-like I/O]) can be troublesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple: Your code is not calling any function, but just building them and leaving them alone.

Just add `main()` right before `print("completed")` so the code calls that function.

Note 1: Why are you reading the text file over and over again inside the loop, and why opening it manually? Auto-close it by the:

```
with open(word_file, "r") as f:
    Words = f.read().splitlines()
```

code before `gen()`.

Note 2: What is `seed` doing? You defined it but haven't used it anywhere.

Note 3: Please check your indentation before posting a question.